# Most efficient way to replace thousands of strings in a giant file

Tags: string, bash, replace

I have about a half million records that look somewhat like this:

```
=001  000016937
=005  20160611133900.0
=007  ta
=008  930824s1990\\\\cl\\\\\\\\\\\\000\0\spa\u
=041  1 $aspaspaeng
=084  \ $aTV/UdeC/G589s
=100  1 $aGonzález Ugas, Jorge$e, autor$e, autor
=245  10$aSincronización de estro y fertilidad en bovinos de carne sincronizados con un análogo de PGF-2 alfa vía intravulvosubmucosa
=260  \ $aChillán:$bUniversidad de Concepción,$c1990
=300  \ $a48 páginas$bcuadros
=336  \ $atext$btxt$2rdacontent
=337  \ $aunmediated$bn$2rdamedia
=338  \ $avolume$bnc$2rdacarrier
=502  \ $aMemoria de título (Méd. Veterinario)
=504  \ $aIncluye Bibliografía
=520  \ $aCon el fin de establecer la eficacia de la administración de 0,45 mgr de Tiaprost vía intravulvosubmucosa en la inducción de estro y determinar la fertilidad de los sistemas de inseminación artificial a tiempo fijo, con detección de estro y monta dirigida, se trataron 134 vacas y vaquillas de carne divididas en 3 grupos: grupo 1=56 vaquillas; grupo 2=39 [24 vaquillas y 15 vacas] y grupo 3=39 vaquillas. Cada grupo recibió un manejo nutricional diferente. El Tiaprost se administró luego de detectar la presencia de un cuerpo luteo. A las vaquillas del grupo 1 se les detectó calor 3 veces al día durante 45 minutos y se inseminaron con semen congelado a un tiempo prefijado de 80 hrs. Los animales que no entraron en calor en un tiempo de 5 días post-tratamiento volvieron a ser tratados con PGF-2 alfa 10-12 días después; se detectó calor y realizó monta dirigida. Las hembras del grupo 2 se inseminaron a las 80 hrs. después del tratamiento sin detectar calor; y a las vaquillas del grupo 3 se les realizó monta dirigida con toro 12 hrs. después de iniciado el calor. Todas las hembras tratadas se palparon 60-90 días post-tratamiento para diagnosticar preñez. En el grupo 1 se obtuvo un lapso tratamiento-estro promedio de 42,5 hrs.[8-96 hrs.], un 100 por ciento de respuesta al tratamiento dentro de las primeras 96 hrs. post-tratamiento y una duración del celo de 19,22 hrs.[8-36 hrs] con moda de 18 hrs. Se obtuvo un 69,9 por ciento de preñez para el grupo 1; 33,1 por ciento en el grupo 2 [29.1 por ciento en vaquillas y 40 por ciento en vacas] y un 79.9 por ciento en el grupo 3. Se concluyó que la administración de 0,45 mgr de Tiaprost vía intravulvosubmucosa es efectiva en inducir estro en hembras bovinas de carne y la fertilidad es comparable a la obtenida con monta natural. La fertilidad es superior al emplear la detección de estros e inseminar a tiempo prefijado [80 hrs.] o cubrir con monta natural [12 hrs. después de iniciado el calor]
=520  \ $aque al inseminar a las 80 hrs. sin previa detección de calor. Se obtuvieron resultados aceptables al comparar la inseminación artificial a tiempo prefijado [80 hrs.] detectando calor con monta natural en vaquillas sincronizadas con Tiaprost vía intravulvosubmucosa.
=650  \4$aVaquillas
=650  \4$aGanado Vacuno de Carne
```

However, the value in the 001 field is incorrect for many thousands of items. I have a mapping file of what needs to be there that looks like this:

```
000016937       000138905
000022242       000142318
000022736       000125671
000023118       000141783
000031516       000165088
000068203       000165324
000071245       000132319
000081724       000163695
000093665       000237196
```

Desired output would be something like:

```
=001  000138905
=005  20160611133900.0
=007  ta
=008  930824s1990\\\\cl\\\\\\\\\\\\000\0\spa\u
=041  1 $aspaspaeng
=084  \ $aTV/UdeC/G589s
=100  1 $aGonzález Ugas, Jorge$e, autor$e, autor
=245  10$aSincronización de estro y fertilidad en bovinos de carne sincronizados con un análogo de PGF-2 alfa vía intravulvosubmucosa
=260  \ $aChillán:$bUniversidad de Concepción,$c1990
=300  \ $a48 páginas$bcuadros
=336  \ $atext$btxt$2rdacontent
=337  \ $aunmediated$bn$2rdamedia
=338  \ $avolume$bnc$2rdacarrier
=502  \ $aMemoria de título (Méd. Veterinario)
=504  \ $aIncluye Bibliografía
=520  \ $aCon el fin de establecer la eficacia de la administración de 0,45 mgr de Tiaprost vía intravulvosubmucosa en la inducción de estro y determinar la fertilidad de los sistemas de inseminación artificial a tiempo fijo, con detección de estro y monta dirigida, se trataron 134 vacas y vaquillas de carne divididas en 3 grupos: grupo 1=56 vaquillas; grupo 2=39 [24 vaquillas y 15 vacas] y grupo 3=39 vaquillas. Cada grupo recibió un manejo nutricional diferente. El Tiaprost se administró luego de detectar la presencia de un cuerpo luteo. A las vaquillas del grupo 1 se les detectó calor 3 veces al día durante 45 minutos y se inseminaron con semen congelado a un tiempo prefijado de 80 hrs. Los animales que no entraron en calor en un tiempo de 5 días post-tratamiento volvieron a ser tratados con PGF-2 alfa 10-12 días después; se detectó calor y realizó monta dirigida. Las hembras del grupo 2 se inseminaron a las 80 hrs. después del tratamiento sin detectar calor; y a las vaquillas del grupo 3 se les realizó monta dirigida con toro 12 hrs. después de iniciado el calor. Todas las hembras tratadas se palparon 60-90 días post-tratamiento para diagnosticar preñez. En el grupo 1 se obtuvo un lapso tratamiento-estro promedio de 42,5 hrs.[8-96 hrs.], un 100 por ciento de respuesta al tratamiento dentro de las primeras 96 hrs. post-tratamiento y una duración del celo de 19,22 hrs.[8-36 hrs] con moda de 18 hrs. Se obtuvo un 69,9 por ciento de preñez para el grupo 1; 33,1 por ciento en el grupo 2 [29.1 por ciento en vaquillas y 40 por ciento en vacas] y un 79.9 por ciento en el grupo 3. Se concluyó que la administración de 0,45 mgr de Tiaprost vía intravulvosubmucosa es efectiva en inducir estro en hembras bovinas de carne y la fertilidad es comparable a la obtenida con monta natural. La fertilidad es superior al emplear la detección de estros e inseminar a tiempo prefijado [80 hrs.] o cubrir con monta natural [12 hrs. después de iniciado el calor]
=520  \ $aque al inseminar a las 80 hrs. sin previa detección de calor. Se obtuvieron resultados aceptables al comparar la inseminación artificial a tiempo prefijado [80 hrs.] detectando calor con monta natural en vaquillas sincronizadas con Tiaprost vía intravulvosubmucosa.
=650  \4$aVaquillas
=650  \4$aGanado Vacuno de Carne
```

There are many ways this problem could be solved, but I'm hoping for a quick and dirty way (ie a few lines of script as opposed to a program) as I expect to encounter similar situations again. My gut reaction was to just hand it to sed, but I got an "Argument list too long" which puzzled me because

```
sh-4.2$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

and I don't have that many values to map. That the correct numbers overlap with the incorrect ones is not a problem -- I'll just prefix the former so only the wrong ones can get fixed.

Total file size of the records is just over a half gig so there should be some options.

Comment: Show your sed command where you got that error.

Comment: Considering the large number of fields to process, I would do this with python or Perl (or some other language) than bash.  They are all much faster than bash, and offer great tools to make it easier.

Comment: Kyle, `ARG_MAX` counts bytes, not arguments. (And it includes you environment variables).

Comment: @glennjackman, sed command was basically having a single massive sed command containing thousands of lines of replacement expressions. Your question made me realize that I was going about it the wrong way so when I set it up as a script file, it worked.

 I like your awk solution as it's more versatile for the type of work that I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, this is a natural fit for awk:

```sh
tmp=$(mktemp)
awk '
  NR == FNR {map[$1] = $2; next}
  $1 == "=001" && $2 in map {$2 = map[$2]}
  {print}
' mappingFile bigFile > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" bigFile
```

Comment: I don't think that will preserve the double-width whitespace, if that's important. But maybe I'm wrong; i didn't try it.

Comment: It doesn't preserve the whitespace which is important, but it's an easy fix so it's not a problem

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `ed` if available/acceptable, with the `bash` shell using Process Substitution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s giant_file.txt < <(
  printf '%s\n' 'g|.|s|^\([^[:blank:]]*\)*[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)$|g/^=001 /s/\1/\2/|' '$a' w . ,p Q |
  ed -s mapping_file.txt
)
```

Note: It will edit the file *in-place*

---

This version will just output to `stdout`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s giant_file.txt < <(
  printf '%s\n' 'g|.|s|^\([^[:blank:]]*\)*[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)$|g/^=001 /s/\1/\2/|' '$a' ,p Q . ,p Q |
  ed -s mapping_file.txt
)
```